# Getting an error while using angular and npm

Tags: angular, npm

```
Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser' builder's node package.
```

This is the error and when I run `npm start` the console goes to this

```
weba11ytracker-frontend@0.0.0 start
ng serve --configuration=local
```

but then stops.

I've tried

- `PS C:\wcag\WebA11yTracker\weba11ytracker-frontend> set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`
- `PS C:\wcag\WebA11yTracker\weba11ytracker-frontend> ng build --configuration=production`
- Deleting and reinstalling npm

Comment: what is the output if npm i ?

Answer (score 0):

this is ok to show you this lines.

```
weba11ytracker-frontend@0.0.0 start
ng serve --configuration=local
```

but if you have error after that

Verify that you have the necessary dependencies installed by running the following command in your project directory:

```
npm install
```

Check your package.json file to ensure that the '@angular-devkit/build-angular' package is listed as a dependency. If it is missing, you can add it by running the following command:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

If the issue persists, you can try deleting the 'node_modules' folder and reinstalling all dependencies by running the following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules

npm install
```

Comment: I tried deleting the node module then reinstalling npm but it did not work.